# Backtracking - How do I solve this variant of "rat in a maze"?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I recently appeared for a job interview where i was asked the popular RAT IN A MAZE PROBLEM where there is a maze represented by a 2 dimensional array which contains 0's and 1's for open paths and walls respectively and we have to print the shortest path.

I solved the problem using backtracking and also printed all possible paths.

But then the interviewer increased the toughness level and asked me to solve the same question with a new condition where the rat can trip "K" number of walls where K is input by the user.

Now I tried a lot but couldn't figure out how to find the shortest path if tripping K walls was allowed.I thought whether it could be solved via DYNAMIC PROGRAMMING but couldn't implement it ultimately.

The interviewer also didn't reveal the solution.
Can anyone explain solution of this problem?

Comment: By "trip" walls, do you mean move through or remove walls?

Comment: This is a variant you can solve with Dijkstra where every node also stores which walls have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

You may want to start by reading through the basic BFS algorithm linked to above if you're not already familiar enough with it, because the below largely builds off of that.

- For every cell, we need to store the number of walls we've gone through to get to that cell - call this `walls`.
- Start with a queue containing our starting cell.
- Let `walls` of the starting cell be `0`.
- Repeatedly set the current cell equal to the first element of the queue (which we remove).

  - If the current cell is the target cell, print out the path and we're done.
  - If the current cell is a wall, increase `current.walls` by 1.
  - If `current.walls > K`, do nothing.
  - For each neighbour: (walls and open cells)

    If `neighbour.walls` is not initialised (meaning we haven't been there before) or `current.walls < neighbour.walls` (meaning the new path has less walls),
    then set `neighbour.wall = current.walls` and add `neighbour` to the queue.

To actually be able to print out the path, create a map which maps any cell with its `walls` to the cell we came from to get there (and it's `walls`). It won't work to simply map a cell to the previous cell, as previous cells on a path can be overridden if it has a lower value of `K`.

You can also store the entire path, but that's a whole lot less efficient.

The time complexity is `O(rows*columns*K)` and the space complexity is `O(rows*columns)`.

---

A lot of the complexity here is as a result of needing to deal with a scenario like this:
(you can imagine this being part of a larger grid)

[image]

If we have a big enough `K`, we can just cross the two walls (the green path) and reach the top-right cell in 2 moves.

If `K` is not big enough, we need to go around (the blue path), which will take 4 moves.

Thus we do a regular BFS, but also keep track of how many walls we've gone through for each cell, so if we get to the top-right cell after going around, we see that it was previously reached by crossing 2 walls (instead of the current 0), thus we keep going from there in case the path using 2 walls ends up needing to go through too many walls.

Comment: Aren't you wasting knock-throughs by potentially knocking through to places you've already been? Shouldn't you wait until you've mapped the part of the maze that you can reach normally, and then decide where to knock through?

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for the solution.Could you please explain the rationale behind the following:                                                                                      If neighbour.walls is initialised and current.walls < neighbour.walls, do nothing.
Otherwise set neighbour.wall = current.wall & add neighbour to the queue.                                                                                                                         I think if current.wall <neighbour.wall then we should set neighbour.walls=current.walls

Comment: @aryan You're right, it should've been `>=`, not `<=`.